How can I set an element to flex-1, and then prevent it from growing more than that and forcing scroll on its children?
I have a layout, header + content + footer.
The header and the footer both have static heights.
The container has flex flex-col and the content has flex-1.
As long as the content inside the content element is not that much, everything is OK. But when I put more content in it, it grows vertically. I want to prevent it from growing vertically and force a vertical scroll on it.
Something like flex-1 max-h-flex-1. I know we don't have max-h-flex-1 in Tailwind. But you got the idea.
I can't use static length values. Therefore please only answer using flex or grid, or any other fluid way.
How can I achieve that functionality?

See what you can do it you can the class below which makes the screen into a full height and the makes it into the output which you want.
<div class="flex flex-col h-screen">
  <header class="h-16 bg-gray-200">Header</header>
  <main class="flex-1 overflow-y-auto">
    <div class="p-4">
      // Your content goes here
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="h-16 bg-gray-200">Footer</footer>
</div>


Other people's answers are good, but I'd like to add that you can also use sticky to achieve a similar effect. The feature of this approach is that you can use the page scrollbar instead of defining a new scroll element:
<article class="flex min-h-dvh flex-col text-center">
  <header class="sticky top-0 h-36 bg-amber-500">Header</header>
  <main class="h-[100rem] grow bg-emerald-100">Your content</main>
  <footer class="sticky bottom-0 h-36 bg-sky-500">Footer</footer>
</article>


Demo on Tailwind Play.
